# Bitbucket - как найти раннюю версию класса?

Tags: search, bitbucket, history

Есть у меня проект месячной давности. У него есть одна ветка **master**, в которую каждый день вносятся коммиты. Нужно найти класс, которого сейчас нет. Его нет на моём компьютере(есть одна архивная копия), а в удалённом репозитории его не могу отыскать - в интерфейсе **bitbucket** нет опции "найти файл". Поясните по шагам, как это сделать.

Comment: Файл я отыскал следующим способом: руками перебирал коммиты, пока не нашёл его упоминание. Потом нажал **ShowSource** и увидел всё содержимое. Мне этот способ не нравится, поскольку есть вероятность, что файл найден не будет, но, видимо, придётся смириться. P.S Ответа не смотрел, сейчас посмотрю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Склонируйте себе репозиторий и работайте с ним полноценно. Если это Git, то:

```
git clone https://YOUR_LOGIN@bitbucket.org/YOUR_LOGIN/REPOSITORY_NAME.git
```

А затем ищите:

```
git log --since="2016-06-22" path_to_chanded_file
```